# Hidden component take extra space

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have a form on which I have a combo box. On the change of the combo box I am loading a new panel below existing panel and the check-box in the existing Panel into the form.

If i do not render the check-box it works perfectly. But when I render check-box, it eats up space between existing panel and new panel. Notmally it has 5px space but while rendering check-box and panel it decreases to 1px between check-box and new panel.

Here is xhtml code:

```
<ui:define name="body">
<f:view>
  <h:form id="editForm">
      <h:outputText value="Target Source Types"/>
      <h:panelGroup>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="collectorSettings">
          <h:selectOneMenu id="collectorType"
                           value="#{targetSource.object.type}"
                           rendered="#{empty targetSource.object.id}"
                           <f:ajax event="change" 
                                   onevent="selectCollectorType"
                                   render="overrideProvisioningTextPanel overrideProvisioningPanel targetCollectors targetCollectorsTextPanel"
                                   execute="@this"
                                   listener="#{targetSource.handleOverrideProvisioningAction}"/>
            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="#{msgs.select_collector_type}"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{targetSource.collectorTypes}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="fixedCollectorType" value="#{empty targetSource.object.type ? 'None' : targetSource.object.type}"
                           rendered="#{not empty targetSource.object.id}"
                           disabled="true"
                           readonly="true">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{empty targetSource.object.type ? 'None' : targetSource.object.type}"
                          itemLabel="#{empty targetSource.object.type ? msgs.none : targetSource.object.type}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
      </h:panelGroup>

      <h:panelGroup id = "overrideProvisioningTextPanel">
          <h:outputText value="Override Default Provisioning" 
                        rendered="#{not empty targetSource.object.type and !targetSource.overridenProvisioningToggle}"/>
      </h:panelGroup>
      <h:panelGroup id = "overrideProvisioningPanel">
          <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="provisioningOverridden" 
                               value="#{targetSource.provisioningOverridden}"
                               rendered="#{not empty targetSource.object.type and !targetSource.overridenProvisioningToggle}"
                               readonly="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}">
                               <f:ajax event="click" render="targetCollectors targetCollectorsTextPanel"/>
          </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
      </h:panelGroup>

      <h:panelGroup id="targetCollectorsTextPanel">
          <h:outputText value="Provisioning Action"
                        rendered="#{targetSource.provisioningOverridden}"/>
      </h:panelGroup>
      <h:panelGroup>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="targetCollectors">
          <h:selectOneMenu id="collector"
                           value="#{targetSource.object.targetCollector}"
                           rendered="#{targetSource.provisioningOverridden}"
            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="#{msgs.select_provisioning_collector}"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{targetSource.targetCollectors}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
    </a4j:outputPanel>

    <a4j:outputPanel id="configSettings">
      <h:messages infoClass="formInfo" warnClass="formWarn" errorClass="formError" fatalClass="formError"/>

      <h:panelGroup  rendered="#{not empty targetSource.object.collector}">
        <ui:include src="#{targetSource.configPage}"/>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </a4j:outputPanel>

    <div class="buttonRow">
      <ui:fragment rendered="#{sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}">
        <h:commandButton id="targetSourceSave" action="#{targetSource.saveAction}" value="#{msgs.button_save}" styleClass="primaryBtn" 
                         onclick="return isSaveOk(this);"/>
      </ui:fragment>
      <h:commandButton id="targetSourceCancel" action="#{targetSource.cancelAction}" value="#{msgs.button_cancel}" styleClass="secondaryBtn" />
    </div>

    <a4j:commandButton id="refreshTargetSourceRulesButton"
                       style="display:none"
                       immediate="true"
                       render="targetSourceRulesPanel"/>

    <a4j:commandButton id="selectTypeButton" action="#{targetSource.selectType}" style="display:none"
                       render="configSettings, collectorSettings"
                       oncomplete="initializeSelectedConfigPage();"/>

  </h:form>
</f:view>
```

Javascript:

```
function initializeSelectedConfigPage() {
        var collectorType = $('editForm:collectorType').value;
    if ( collectorType == 'Windows FileShare Collector') {
            displayAppropriatePane('fileShareInfos', 'button0');
        } else if ( collectorType == 'SharePoint Collector') {
            displayAppropriatePane('siteCollectionConfig', 'button0');
        } else if ( collectorType == 'SharePoint Online Collector') {
            displayAppropriatePane('siteCollectionConfig', 'button0');
        }
        else if ( collectorType == 'PE2 RACFCollector') {
            displayAppropriatePane('siteCollectionConfig', 'button0');
        }
        else if ( collectorType == 'PE2 ACF2Collector') {
            displayAppropriatePane('siteCollectionConfig', 'button0');
        }
        else if ( collectorType == 'PE2 TSSCOLLECTOR') {
            displayAppropriatePane('siteCollectionConfig', 'button0');
        }
    }
```

Note:
I am using JSF ajax and rendered property to toggle the components.

Comment: This doesn't look like any xhtml I've ever seen. Can you post a working jsfiddle example that shows the problem? I cannot recreate it like this.

Comment: Looks like JavaServer Faces, or so it seems when I Googled a tag.

Comment: Yeah it is JSF. Added tag for jsf.

Comment: @CODEFISH: please hover with your mouse on top of `[xhtml]` tag which you placed on the question and carefully read the description and then click through to the "info" link and carefully read it as well. Finally, please take action accordingly. On the other hand, when asking in HTML/CSS/JS context, you'd better post the JSF-generated HTML output instead of raw JSF source code. HTML users generally have no clue about JSF (nor about XHTML, by the way). Once you get the answer in HTML/CSS/JS context, all you need to do in JSF side is making sure that it generates exactly the desired HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: Sorry. I will read the tags from now on.

Comment: @StephanMuller: I warmly recommend you to read the XHTML wiki page as well as you seem to be the kind of HTML user who participated in the ridiculous XHTML overhype leading to a severe misunderstanding of XHTML in general: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xhtml/info

Answer (score 0):

wild guess:

the css property

```
visibility:hidden
```

hides the element but keeps it´s measurements as if the element was shown

use

```
display:none
```

to also hide the measurements as if the element was shown

Comment: I am using JSF ajax and rendered property to toggle the components.